# Select only the inputs that allow for text input

Tags: jquery, input

Using jQuery, I need to detect whenever an input with in given container is changed.

To better meet the criteria for this task, I wish to handle the `'change'` event for non-text inputs (such as checkboxes, radio buttons and selects), and the '`keyup'` event for the rest.  This is because text type inputs don't fire the `'change'` event until they are un-focused.

I my wildest dreams, the below code would accomplish this, but in reality `:text` only picks up `input[type="text"]` elements, **but not** number, password, textarea, etc.

```
$('#admin-bar-button-page').on('change', '.abb-option:input:not(:text)', function(){
    t._onSettingChange();
});
$('#admin-bar-button-page').on('keyup', '.abb-option:text', function(){
    t._onSettingChange();
});
```

I can of course manually add each type of input to the relevant handler, but that's time consuming and there is no guarantee that the fields displayed on the page won't change in the future.

Is there a way of selecting only inputs that allow for text input for the `'keyup'` event handler, and only those that do not for the `'change'` event handler?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo on my part. Updating now.

Comment: you could add a class to every input you want 'watch' and then use the class name as a selector... would that work for you?